# change option of <select> Dynamically with javascript and read it on asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have :  select  id="select1" runat="server"> option>choose something /option> /select>

and I have this javascript function

```
var op = document.getElementById("select1");

for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    op.options[i] = new Option(arr[i]);  
}
```

now after this function, the select has more `<option>`.

Now When pressing on `asp:button`, I want to be able to read(on server side) the new selected value.

unfortunately when the server process the page ,all the selcet1 values that was given by the javascript function are gone and the server always see the orignal value of the select1 ("choose something").

so, I can I read, on server side, the new options of the select1, that was generte by the javascript ?

Thanks for any help

Baaroz

Comment: ok I didn't know I almost got a answers

Comment: Not a problem, @baaroz. Checking the answers "rewards" the people who worked on your question, showing them some appreciation.  Also, it shows others that the question was successfully answered.  You can still go back and check those answers, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the values by finding it using `Request.Form`, like

```
foreach(string key in Request.Form) {
    Response.Write(key + ": " + Request.Form[key] + "<br />");
}
```

You might also just find it by using `Request.Form["select1"];`

Comment: But How can I know what the client choose from the select options

Comment: If it was an answer, please click the checkmark to your left. Same goes with all your other questions as Jason Gennaro pointed out.